# iOS (iPhone) Development - Local notifications randomly fire while app is not running

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

We've encountered a very odd problem with regards to local notifications firing while our app is not running. By not running, I mean it is completely terminated (does not appear in the task list when you double-tab the home button).

Under normal running conditions, while the app is backgrounded, if the device is motionless for more than X number of seconds, the app will generate a local notification with warning a sound. 15 seconds after that, if no action has been taken, another local notification is generated with an emergency message.

Seemingly at random, hours or days after the app was terminated, the device will suddenly report a warning notification, followed by the emergency notification approximately 15 seconds later, just as though the app was running normally in the background. As stated, we have verified that the app is not listed in the running tasks lists, and appears to be completely terminated.

The app is registered for long-term background processing modes for location, audio, and VOIP.

When the app terminates (in applicationWillTerminate), we perform cleanup, which includes shutting down and nullifying timers, cancelling local notifications, etc.

I have two theories:

1. I wonder if these "ghost" notifications are merely old
   notifications that were queued up while the app was running, but
   were never executed until now (my question is then why is the time
   difference between the warning and emergency notification still
   respected).
2. Is it possible that the app is "secretly" running somewhere in the deep background. If so, it appears as though the device periodically "wakes" the app up; if this is the case, what is the device using as criteria for this "wakeup call".

I wonder if anybody has encountered this odd issue, and if so, how we resolve the issue?

P.S - We are quite new to iOS development, so apologies in advance if we've overlooked something completely obvious

**Update #1**
Using log messages through xCode, I have observed applicationWillTerminate being consistently called when the application is shut down via task bar closure. There does seem to be a lot of debate about whether this behaviour can be relied upon, though, so I won't say conclusively whether I believe my observation to be consistent, but I am leaning in that direction. Any further insight on this, however, would be appreciated!

**Update #2**
I tried a new approach last night; until now we were scheduling a notification to fire "now" by using the **`[application scheduleLocalNotifications]`** method, and setting the the date to the current time. Instead, I used the **`[application presentLocalNotificationNow]`** method, and supplied no date/time. The app still functions properly, however it did not resolve the problem, as the 'ghost' notifications triggered randomly last night while the app was not running. I am wondering now if the issue is less of an 'old notification'-related problem, and more to do with the application being "woken up" due to some trigger as a result of our long-term background execution registration.

Comment: I am not sure applicationWillTerminate is always called before your app gets killed so your cleanup may not always have a chance to cleanup.

Comment: @onnoweb Yeah we had the same thought. According to the apple documentation, applicationWillTerminate is never called for apps that support background execution - since we have registered for long term background processing, I wonder if this applies to our situation. So, if the app is shut down manually (double-tab home, etc), what happens; does the OS simply reclaim the memory in the same was it does when the device runs out of RAM? Either way, what would cause it to suddenly "wake up" at seemingly random times?

Comment: Well, you've set all three background modes for your app. So there are a variety of triggers that can go off causing your app to load in the background. I am curious why you have audio in addition to voip and location? Or why not just voip alone and set a setKeepAliveTimer for every 10 minutes or so?

Comment: You're right, I don't think we need audio any more. It was used back when we were trying to accomplish something that turned out to be a dead end. Regarding what you said about triggers causing the app to be loaded, it sounds like perhaps I can simply put a piece of logic to prevent notifications during "off hours", assuming these aren't just lingering queued notifications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once your app has scheduled a UILocalNotification, they are handled by the operating system, not your app. So even if your app killed, they still go off.

So no, your app isn't still secretly running in the deep background, those are just notifications that you already scheduled that are going off. Are you possibly setting a repeatInterval on the notifications?

You can clear all the notifications by using:

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

It's possible that your applicationWillTerminate is not getting called before your app gets killed as onnoweb stated. I'm not sure if that always gets called when the user closes the app in the task bar or not.

---

Edited to respond to comment:

My first thought is that you seem to be scheduling UILocalNotifications with incorrect fire dates. I suggest that you check the way that you're scheduling them. The only way that they could be going off a day after your app has been killed is if you scheduled them while your app was still running.

---

Edited to respond to further comment:

Teeg - I think that it's possible that applicationWillTerminate sometimes gets called when you kill the app, but is not guaranteed to be called. From what I've read, if your app is in a suspended state, the method does not get called. I don't know exactly how apps with long running background tasks work, but perhaps it switches between background and suspended states. I'm not sure. But the thing is, calling

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

will cancel all your notifications. So if one goes off after that, that is evidence that the method wasn't called. I guess another possibility could be that the method was called, but the app didn't have enough time to cancel all the notifications before it was killed. I'm not too sure about how much time you get to do stuff there. I would suggest again though that your best bet is to find out why those notifications are being scheduled in the first place.

Comment: Cool, thanks for your answer. Presently, we do the cancelAllLocalNotifications, but we do so in the applicationWillTerminate function; We're thinking the same as well, that this function is not being called as expected due to the background processing. Also, we have the repeatInterval set to zero, which should be "no repeat", as my understanding goes.

So if the execution of applicationWillTerminate is debatable, keeping in mind that local notifications are also generated in the background, where do you think would be better to shove the cancelAllLocalNotifications message?

Comment: applicationWillTerminate is basically *never* called in the multitasking world of iOS 4 and later. It is a dead letter. Use the fact that you are about to be suspended as a sign that you might also be terminated.

Comment: `applicationWillTerminate` is most certainly called when the user manually terminates the app via double pressing the home button, then holding the running app icon until the minus badge appears, then tapping the badge.  You will need to put your logic also in `applicationDidEnterBackground` as that method will not fire if the app is terminated...

Comment: @TReddy Yes, we have our application background code in that function. Also, I just verified with log messages that applicationWillTerminate does indeed get called as expected when shut down, despite our multi-tasking registration.

Comment: @Darren - Just noticed your update, thanks for keeping in touch. Like I said, my problem is that I don't know of any other method in which to place the cancelAllLocalNotifications method, other than in applicationWillTerminate, since the app creates local notifications while it is in the background. Re: guarantee of applicationWillTerminate being called, you could be right, however using log messages I've seen it being consistently called when the app is shut down, so I'm really not sure about this one. Check out the question update for some more info based on everybody's suggestions so far.

Comment: Very strange problem! I was not aware that an app could be "woken up" if it had been explicitly closed in the multitask bar. That seems unlikely to me, as it would seem to go agains Apple's design principles - it a user has shutdown an app, they're not going to expect it to open up again on its own. Good luck finding the issue, and post here if you figure out what's going on!

Comment: Accepting this answer since it contains all very good information which should technically solve this very odd problem, were this application not completely insane. The situation we've observed so far is that, from the point when the app is closed and shut down, the "woken up" background behaviour is seen 1-3 times before ceasing completely. This is pretty well consistent, and can happen hours, or days after the app is shut down. Seems to be something extremely unusual going on, and we just can't seem to pin it down. Thanks all for the help!

Comment: The only other thing that I could suggest would be to make a sample project that just contains the alerts setting mechanism. See if the the same behaviour is still observed. It it is, make the project available for download from github or dropbox, and then maybe someone can look at it and find out what's happening.